# How to find post data when submit a username from login from yahoo login in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, request, web-crawler

When I submit a username from yahoo login from like below image

[image]

It will post this to yahoo server.

My question is why I can not find any thing about my username from post information fromChrome since this is a post with content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded.(i assume i will have sometihng like payload or formdata in chrome debug mode)

[image]

My goal is to use request module from node.js to simulate post behavior.

Comment: Close the "Request Headers" tab, "Form Data" should be at the very bottom ...

Comment: Thanks for reply but there is nothing at the bottom after Request Headers.

Comment: Not at the bottom, but _below_ it. Works fine for me, and shows the expected data on the Yahoo login page.

Comment: Weired...what is your Request URL? Mine is just https://login.yahoo.com/

Comment: Actually yahoo login page is on https and data before post is encrypted by https certifcate.

Comment: @VijayRaheja Hmm.. thanks. That means i cannot know what it post to server? or how to do it?

Comment: For this  you have to use Fiddler, it will capture yahoo https certificate and here with setting in fiddler you can see posted traffic as encrypted also. But this setting changes in all versions of fiddler for which you have to google it.

Comment: Appreciated for the information. I will try it.

Comment: @Vijay HTTPS has nothing to do with this, dev tools have access to the data before any encryption takes place.

Comment: Yes, just `https://login.yahoo.com/` - and it shows the posted data fine.

Comment: @CBroe nothing can find from my chrome,really werid.maybe is chrome version?

Comment: If anybody can see post data in https, then what is the use of it. Anybody can interpret in between.